# How to setup port forwarding on Google Cloud

Tags: ssl, google-compute-engine

I am trying to forward port 443 (SSL) on an external IP address on a Google Cloud VM, to port 6984 internally (using CouchDB)   I am trying to do this so that I may use LetsEncrypt, which requires port 443 available to configure new certs.

I am looking at [forwarding rules](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/network/forwarding-rules) but see no way to specify a port mapping, only instance mapping.

How can I forward port 443 to port 6984 on a single Google Cloud VM?

Answer (score 1):

What you're referring to is actually called [Port Address Translation (PAT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#One-to-many_NAT), and is not directly supported by Google Cloud Platform.

Instead, you might be able to reconfigure the software in question to listen on the desired port (6984).

*EDIT:* Let's Encrypt is [sunsetting and deprecating TLS-SNI challenges](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/2018-01-11-update-regarding-acme-tls-sni-and-shared-hosting-infrastructure/50188), so you'll need to use HTTP-01 (port 80) or DNS-01 (DNS record) for Let's Encrypt instead -- so, if you use one of those, you can have CouchDB run on any port you want other than port 80.